# why th Scaffold widget is a StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

by coincidence, I looked at the `Scaffold` widget implementation source code, then I noticed that it's a `StateFulWidget`

why it's a `StatefullWidget`?
what parts or things need it to be `StatefullWidget`?

Comment: I'm not speaking as an authoritative source on this but after looking at the source code, I would have two guesses as to why it is a stateful application

1. To keep track of the persistent bottom sheet, described here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart#L1449-L1451 the widget must have state

2. Since the Scaffold is meant to be a top level widget that your app lives inside of, if it were not stateful, when changes are made to it, it would need to rebuild, and then as a result all child widgets (your app) would also be rebuilt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Scaffold` widget has a feature called `drawer`, which has a state for itself, so when you need to open it, `Scaffold` changes its state and open it. Other feature like showing `snackBars`, `BottomSheet` and `FloatingActionButton` do the same.

Comment: yes it has. @Moustapha